# The new UI has two search fields on an iPhone and does not display properly

Tags: bug, user-interface, searching, search

I noticed yesterday that the UI for AskUbuntu has changed, but I’m having an issue with the search field on an iPhone with the Safari browser. As it stands, there are two spyglasses in the top menu bar, and when either one is selected, the search field is not displayed properly.

The symptoms are the same with DuckDuckGo browser as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not just on AskUbuntu and not just iPhone.  It is appearing like this on every SE site that I have looked at today and on Android phones.

Comment: Yes I can confirm this on Android as well - thanks for reporting! 

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog How did you do the smaller images inline? Simply resize yourself? Or is there a way directly?

Comment: It's a pretty cool trick! Make sure to look at my edit's Markdown. In essence I duplicated your links and changed their numbers to `4`, `5`, `6`. Then I added `l` (that's the letter "l", like "lion") before the extension to resize the images (it's an option offered by Imgur). Then I used this format for the inline images: `[![image description][y]][x]`, where `x` is the number of the original link for an image and `y` is the link for the resized image. This way we can keep the original images on click and have smaller versions inline.

Comment: Also see this for more resizing options: [How to reduce image size on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253403/how-to-reduce-image-size-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: And this: [Resizing an image in a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25051/620527)

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** This has been fixed, and the MSE report has been marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

This has been [reported on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398680/1081494), and SE staff are working on fixing it.

<s>I'll update this once it gets fixed.</s>

Comment: Now working for me...

Comment: @andrew.46 Yep, it's been fixed! I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Great news! Thank you 